# how to fetch a real-time changing data into a local server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timestamp, real-time, localserver

we have to develop a local server which will load itself with the real-time data of a industry (particularly time stamped data points like the temperature of a boiler,pressure values etc) which are stored in industrial server and we want to fetch them and populate our server with it, the data is not streamed at server end so how to fetch it continuously and populate the server...

we would like to store only past 2-3 days of history data as time advances, any recommendations about the server and the back end process to be used to fetch data are welcome, we don't have any idea were to start..
please help...

Comment: What is the source of the data?

Comment: What are you interested in? The technologies to use, or just the theory?

Comment: Need more information:
How is the data accessed?
What does it mean " to populate the server"?
What are the volumes? 
etc..

Comment: source of the data is data repository of the industry ...

Comment: we are interested in technologies to be used and the theory too to understand it better, any useful links will help a lot...

Comment: populate a server means fetch the data from remote server of industry and collect it in our local server to publish it via a web service from here...and m totally newbie to this not having much idea about it..what step to take first or any brief explanation will be a like seven heavens...

Comment: and one more thing we are thinking of using the JavaEE technologies with which we are familiar, will this be helpful or totaly new technologies are required for the same, any suggestion other than it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated,
You need to provide more information on how do you intend to populate your server. 
What API do you have for the "real time server"? 
I worked on a management system for solar engery devices 
(i.e - devices that produce electricity from solar energy - they are called photo-volatic cells if I remember correctly). 
In my case these devices had an FTP access , which provided me files with time-based information. 
I constructed a java server that used the following technologies: 
A. [Apache tomcat web container](http://tomcat.apache.org/) - This web container allowed me on one hand to hold java logic, and on the other hand to expose HTTP-based interface to the customer. 
The Java logic was located in a [Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html)- which exposes methods to handle HTTP requests (and allows writing returned data using response objects). 
B. The servlet has an init method, I used it to perform some initialization, such as starting a [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) periodic task to probe the ftp servers of the devices. 
C. I used a database ([postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/) database, which is an open source database) to store configuration for the application, and also to store results. 
D. I used another periodic task to archive old data in an archiving table, so the main data table will hold relatively new data. 
I ran the archiving task once in a few days, and it simple checked for record that were "too" old, inserted them to the archiving table, and deleted them from the main data table. In order to peform this efficiently I have have decided to use a [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html) that I coded on the database. 
E. In order to access the database from the application, I used the [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) object relational mapping technology. 
 
This technology allowed me to define mappings between tables and their relations to java objects, and gave me generated create,read (by-id), delete and updated SQL statements. 
Using the HQL query language, I wrote some more complex queries. 
F. For presentation/client side - I used plain [JSP](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html). 
You may choose other alternatives such as : 
GWT, Apache Wicket, JSF
You may consider using some [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework to have some seperation between the logic and the presentation. Such frameworks can be: 
Spring-MVC , Struts, and many others.
To conclude, you must understand that Java offers you a variety of technologies, you must define requirements well, and then start investigating which technology can meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot this info helped a bit to give a brief start for the project, i'l find more requirements about the project and share the same...

Comment: I would appreciate if you upvote this (you don't have to of course, but people invest time in writing detailed comments, and they in generally like to be credited).

Comment: Apologies, am not able to upvote as i don't have 15 reputation points, which is the minimum criteria to upvote a answer